# SSIS Database Always on AG and Patching

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2017, patching

I am after clarification, when we patch a SQL Server Always on AG environment that has the SSIS database in the AG we remove the SSIS database, patch failover, patch and add the SSIS DB back into the AG once complete.

I feel this process was due to older versions of SQL server not supporting SSIS and Always on AG's, pre 2016 having issues during the upgrade / patch process. I remember having to enable trace flag 902 and resoling the issues.

Is this still the case or are newer SQL versions able to cope?